# What are the differences between REST.JsonReflect and Data.DBXJSONReflect?

Tags: json, delphi, rest, marshalling, datasnap

Delphi introduced a new JSON marshaler in unit `REST.JsonReflect`, a similar JSON marshaler exists in unit `Data.DBXJSONReflect`.  Both units introduce `TJSONConverters` to create `TJSONMarshal` and `TJSONUnMarshal` instances.

- what are the differences between `REST.JsonReflect.TJSONConverters` and `Data.DBXJSONReflect.TJSONConverters`?
- will `REST.JsonReflect.TJSONConverters` replace `Data.DBXJSONReflect.TJSONConverters`?
- are there any situations where I should use `Data.DBXJSONReflect.TJSONConverters` instead of `REST.JsonReflect.TJSONConverters`?

Comment: I always use SuperObject, it doesn't come with Delphi but most developers prefer it.

Comment: @JerryDodge: I use `SuperObject` before but switch to `System.JSON.pas`.  I think Delphi build in JSON library works better with DataSnap server methods.

Comment: One more vote to go ...